# nullpointerexception error on cancel or closing dialog

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

My problem is when my `showopendialog` appears and I press cancel or the X on the right corner instead of loading some text in my textarea, the console shows the error of `nullpointexception` on my line `String filename=f.getAbsolutePath();`

My action open is on a menu bar.

Thank you.

```
JFileChooser flcFile = new JFileChooser("c:\\");
flcFile.showOpenDialog(null);
File f = flcFile.getSelectedFile();
String filename=f.getAbsolutePath();

    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        txtPersonal.read(br, null);

        br.close();
        txtPersonal.requestFocus();

    }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }
```

Comment: If you cancel, you haven't selected any file. So getSelectedFile() returns null, so if you try calling a method on the null selected file, it throws a NullPointerException. Test the result of showOpenDialog(), before blindly using the selected file. Or at least test that the selected file is not null before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you close without selecting a file, you can't get the absolute path of the file. Always check if a file has been selected by the user by checking the value returned by the `showOpenDialog()` method. Only get the absolute path after this check.

Useful reading: [The JFileChooser docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

```
JFileChooser flcFile = new JFileChooser("c:\\");
int result = flcFile.showOpenDialog(null);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File f = flcFile.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();

    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        txtPersonal.read(br, null);

        br.close();
        txtPersonal.requestFocus();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I modified your code, check the following example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser flcFile = new JFileChooser("c:\\");
        int result = flcFile.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = flcFile.getSelectedFile();
        if (JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION == result) {
            System.out.println("canceled");
        } else if (JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION== result) {
            String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(filename);
        }else{
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to check the return value of the `showOpenDialog` method in order to know the selected option, I hope it help you

cheers.